# Infinitive of Purpose or For

Tags: infinitives, gerund-vs-infinitive, predicate-frames

Could you please tell me which usage is correct ?

'I need money to start a business'

'I need money for starting a business'

Actually the first one sounds more natural to me and also I know for is used for stating purpose of something(or what it is used for) but can we think like money will be used for starting a business (we meant what it will be used for) ?

Comment: 'I need money to start a business' is correct and common.
'I need money for starting a business' might not be wrong but it would be very, very rare.
More importantly, could you get a teacher or classmate or anyone to help you re-phrase *I know for is used for stating purpose of something(or what it is used for) but can we think like money will be used for starting a business (we meant what it will be used for)*?
As it stands, that simply does not work.